# Do I need to flatten an artwork made in Indesign, which will be used for an e-mail blast?

Tags: flatten

I am currently working on an artwork which I plan to use for an email blast and not for print. Since I am new with InDesign, I want to know if I need to flatten the fonts / transparencies like what I normally do in Illustrator.

I also started exploring InDesign and made the artwork somehow interactive. I have already saved it as an interactive PDF but I am not sure if the it will be affected once I upload online or send as an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are publishing your work as email, generally speaking, you have to roll back your ambition to the most basic HTML page, or even to putting in a simple PNG or JPEG bitmap of the entire document, perhaps with slices, depending on how complicated your design is. You also need a plain text version of your document for email readers that either don’t support HTML or have HTML turned off.

Interactive features are not supported by email clients. Maybe there is a little bit of CSS interactivity that can get through, but JavaScript is not going to happen. That would be a security risk.

A good idea is to pretend you are targeting a Web browser from 2005 with JavaScript turned off.

So you don’t do any flattening in your InDesign document, you flatten when you export to HTML or PNG or JPEG.

Comment: Just to extend this answer. Depending on what exactly you want to do, you may upload your pdf online and then send a link to it in your e-mail instead. Obviously you only want to do that if there is enough information justifying it. (its a guide or e-book etc.)

Comment: It is an advert type of document which needs to use links. I ended up using mailchimp since I do not have the luxury of time to code everything.